# Sort order lost when applying upper function in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have configured custom sorting order to a column in spot-fire but when I apply the function Upper on that column in customer expression, the sorting doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to keep the sort order. I don't want to make any changes to the data file.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what it is you are exactly doing? If you are applying a custom sort order on a calculated column, it should not change after adding "Upper" to it.

Comment: It is not a calculated column, say I have a month column and I sort it from jul-jun as the ordering. Now if I plot a graph with x axis as month it works but if change it to upper(month) the sorting doesn't stay

Comment: Ah now I understand. Spotfire reverts back to its natural sort order and I don't think there is much you can do to prevent that. However, have you thought of making a calculated column using `Upper([YourColumn])` and sort that column to your liking?

Comment: @ShuhomChoudhury how are you sorting it? Are you going to Edit > Column Properties > Sort Order and applying a Natural string sort or a Custom sort order?

Comment: @k88 : Yes I am looking for a way without using calculated column.

Comment: @scsimon : Yeah I have used edit column properties and applied custom sort.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a custom sort Spotfire will do a bit by bit comparison to apply your sort condition. Applying an `UPPER` function changes this bit placement and therefore your sort is lost. If you want to use `UPPER` and your custom sort order you will need to inert a calculated column with `Upper([OriginalColumn])` and set your custom sort order on this column as well. Then you can reference it in your visualization. There is no harm in creating this simple calculated column. You will not notice a decrease in performance. You can also cache your calculated column so this conversion doesn't have to be performed every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of changing sort order of custom expressions.

What you can do is to use a calculated column instead of custom expression and change its sort order. (This doesn't make any change in the source file)